# CSS div height inheritance

Tags: html, css

Why `#container2` in Situation 2 doesn't maintain height specified on `#container1`, like it did with width in Situation 1?

Situation 1:

```
<div id="container1" style="width: 300px">
  <div id="container2">
    <img src="landscape.png">
  </div>
</div>
```

[image: 1]

Situation 2:

```
<div id="container1" style="height: 300px">
  <div id="container2">
    <img src="portrait.png">
  </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Percentage height only works if the parent's `height` is defined. In your example `#container2` doesn't have that, which will be using the initial value `auto`. You can set it to `height:100%` or `height:inherit` to make it equal to the height of `#container1`.

```css
#container2 {
  height: 100%; /* or height:inherit; */
}
img {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="container1" style="height: 300px">
  <div id="container2">
    <img src="//dummyimage.com/800">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm still not sure I get why height behaves different from width, because for container2 width I didn't have to specifically inherit its parents width?

Comment: it's designed like that. A block element like div occupies the entire width by default, but height is auto and determined by the content. Imagine, if you set html tag to height:100%, are you expecting everything in the page to be height:100%, that would be make it all unusable.